# SQL Server : updated column turns to blank again after several minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example: I have `column1` and `column2`, I updated some rows of that column.

After several minutes it turns blank again. Any idea on this?

Comment: One explanation would be that the `UPDATE` statements start with a `BEGIN TRANSATION` and that you need to `cOMMIT` the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Not to be too smart, but something else is updating it again :-)  You may want to start SQL Profiler and watch the activity after the update. If an update is occurring, it will capture it and you'll be able to identify the source.

Comment: I watch the SQL Profiler before and after the update it just updated once, it's not updating again. This is so weird.

Comment: Hmmm...yeah, I've never seen that behavior myself...I'm interested to know what you find out

Comment: check for any update trigger on that table. Also, are you profilling for all users ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe replication? Are you updating tables in a replicated database that pulls from or mirrors a live database?